# How are the words defined in the sentencepiece algorithm?

Tags: nlp, tokenization

I am not able to understand how the sentencepiece algorithm solves the problem of handling the languages without a clear-cut concept of words

My exact confusion is:

1. It is mentioned that one of the advantages of the sentencepiece algorithm is that you do not have to do a language-specific pre-tokenization to compute the words
2. The sentencepiece algorithm supports BPE and unigram algorithms
3. However, both the sentencepiece and unigram tokenizers split the corpus into the words as the first step. They use some pre-tokenizer. I have read the huggingface implementation ([unigram](https://huggingface.co/learn/nlp-course/chapter6/7?fw=pt), [BPE](https://huggingface.co/learn/nlp-course/chapter6/5?fw=pt)) for both and that is the first step

Can you help me understand how sentencepiece alleviates the problem of a lack of word demarcation in languages like Japanese?